# How to set conditional termination conditions in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

I wanna solve a quadratic optimization problem with Gurobi in Python. If the problem is solvable in a reasonable time like 3600s, I wanna solve it to optimality. However, if I cannot solve it within 3600s, I wanna solve it with a relative gap = 0.05.
How can I set these conditions in Gurobi?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call, maybe you can wrap your Gurobi call with this timeout, and then change the relative gap.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the Gurobi knowledge base article [How do I set multiple termination criteria for a model?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013419411-How-do-I-set-multiple-termination-criteria-for-a-model-). (Disclaimer: I work for Gurobi and I wrote that KB article).

Comment: that's so awesome to see the KB article owner respond to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please let me know where you have specified the optimality gap?

Comment: @Katankatalan That's explained in the KB article: set TimeLimit=3600; optimize; check the Status; if necessary, optimize again with MIPGap=0.05 and whatever new value you need for TimeLimit.